# What's the difference between `plugins {}` and `pluginManagement.plugins {}` in `settings.gradle`

Tags: gradle

Basically the title.

I couldn't find a simple comparison anywhere, explaining the differences between these two:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
    }

    plugins {
        id "com.some.awesomeplugin" version "1.2.3"
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

// And these:
plugins {
    id "com.another.greatplugin" version "2.1.37"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
}
```

I'm aware that there can be 3 types of plugins in Gradle:

1. Project plugins, whose `apply()` callback is called when the individual `build.gradle` files are evaluated:

```kotlin
class BuildPhasePlugin : Plugin<Project>
```

2. Settings plugins, whose `apply()` callback is called when the `settings.gradle` file is evaluated:

```kotlin
class SettingsPhasePlugin : Plugins<Settings>
```

3. Initialization plugins, whose `apply()` is called when initialization script (`init.gradle`) is evaluated:

```kotlin
class InitPhasePlugin : Plugin<Gradle>
```

I suppose these 3 types of plugin are somehow related to the `plugins {}` block they can be applied in in `settings.gradle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pluginManagement { plugins { ... } }` does not apply any plugin and does not add them to any classpaths, and thus `apply false` is a no-op and should imho actually trigger a syntax error.

This block just centrally defines the versions for plugins when they are used in other places without a version.
Nowadays I would not use this block at all anymore, but instead use a version catalog to centrally define the versions including plugin versions.

The `plugins { ... }` block on top-level actually applies the specified settings plugins (or just adds them to the classpath when used with `apply false`.